# Removing a item using _.without

Tags: javascript, typescript, underscore.js

I am implementing a toggle functionality in an array.
Toggle Code is as follows: Note: the code is TypeScript
How to remove the item when I pass toggleMode(mode) // mode = 1(integer)
when I doing this, it is going into disableMode and executing omit or without but I guess not working.

```
private toggleMode(mode:ConversationMode)
{
    mode = parseInt(mode.toString());
    var modeEnabledCurrently =this.getRuleByMode(mode);

    if (!modeEnabledCurrently)
        this.enableMode(mode);
    else
        this.disableMode(mode);
}
```

Get Rule By Code:

```
getRuleByMode(mode:ConversationMode)
{
    return _.findWhere(this.modes, selfjs.createSimpleObject("ConversationMode", mode));
}
```

Enable and Disable Code:

```
enableMode(mode:ConversationMode) { 
var obj = selfjs.createSimpleObject(ScheduleRule.COL_CONVERSATION_MODE, mode);
        this.modes.push(obj); 
}

disableMode(mode:ConversationMode) { 
this.modes = _.without(this.modes, mode); 
//this.modes = _.omit(this.modes, function(mode, key, object) {
            return _.findWhere(this.modes, selfjs.createSimpleObject(ScheduleRule.COL_CONVERSATION_MODE, mode));
        });
}
```

When I add it shows:

```
modes: Array[2]
  0: undefined
  1: Object
     conversation_mode: 1
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

I dig a little deeper and find out _.findwhere can only work with key,value pair while the _.without work with arrays not objects, so changed the _.findWhere to _.where and used _.without

```
enableMode = function (mode) {
        this.modes.push(mode);
};

disableMode = function (mode) {
        this.modes = _.without(this.modes, mode);
};

getRuleByMode = function (mode) {
        return _.where(this.modes, mode);
};
```